# AS3 Sound.Play(starttime) weird delay

Tags: actionscript-3, audio, mp3

When sending a valid starttime to Sound.play, I hear the beginning of the mp3 file for ~500ms and only then it starts playing from the given starttime.

Anyone had this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is actually a weird issue that flash has.

Sometimes making sure the sample rate is 44.1kHz will help.

Otherwise try this: http://code.google.com/p/standingwave/ it puts the sound file in a cache and should stop the issue.